# нужно вывести 4.000, а программа выводит 4

Tags: c++, вывод, форматирование, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main() {
   double a = 4.000;
   std::cout << a ; // выводит 4, а нужно 4.000
return 0;
}
```

Comment: потому что 4 равно 4.000

Answer (score 2):

А так?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    double a = 4.000;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << a ;
    return 0;
}
```